# XPath to locate an element containing text nodes?

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to locate the content from `<div class="initiative-section__content">...</div>` by using this XPath `"//*[contains(text(),'Created')]/following-sibling::*"`, but it's returning two elements since there is also `"Created Date"`. And I can't figure out how to add "By" to XPath. I tried something like this but it didn't work `"//*[contains(text(),'Created') and contains(text(),'By')]/following-sibling::*"`

Any ideas?

```
<div class="initiative-section__title">
   "Created"
   " By"
</div>
<div class="initiative-section__content">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the space-normalized [***string-value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the `div` element rather than its children text nodes:

```
//div[normalize-space() = "Created By"]/following-sibling::*
```

Note that you might want to narrow the following sibling test to specify the immediate sibling,

```
//div[normalize-space() = "Created By"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

or even the first immediate sibling that must be a `div` element:

```
//div[normalize-space() = "Created By"]/following-sibling::*[1][self::div]
```